# C - get fread parameters from command line arguments

Tags: c

Right now I have my `fread` setup as below. I want to change `bytesize` to a command line argument.

```
fread(buffer, filelen, bytesize, fileptr);
```

I know the required type is 'size_t'. So is it correct if I use:

```
fread(buffer, filelen, (size_t)argv[1], fileptr);
```

Comment: Theoretically, you should use `strtoul()` or thereabouts, but it is unlikely that you're size is going to overflow the values that fit in an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
int bytesize = atoi(argv[1]);
fread(buffer, filelen, bytesize, fileptr);
```

Convert `argv[1]` to integer and pass that to `fread()`.

Answer (score 1):

`argv` contains an array of strings, not integers. You are not far from the correct approach in that you need to convert this string to an integer, but you are not doing it right. C is one of those languages in which a simple type cast does not parse an integer. Check [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) instead, it might help.